# Java runs OK from command line, but gives "Could not find or load main class" from shell script

Tags: java, shell, classpath, redhat

The command below runs fine when I execute it on RedHat 6 from command line:

```
java -cp /my/dir/Dep1.jar:/my/dir/Dep2.jar:/my/dir/MainJar.jar one.of.my.classes.Class1 <args> > log.txt
```

However, when I execute the following script `test1.sh` (which has 755 permissions):

```
#!/bin/sh

export JEXE="java"
export JBDIR="/my/dir"
export ARGS="<args>"
export JARS="${JBDIR}/Dep1.jar:${JBDIR}/Dep2.jar:${JBDIR}/MainJar.jar"

export CLASSPATH=""
for f in `ls ${JBDIR}/*.jar`
do
        export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$f
done

cd "${JBDIR}"
"${JEXE}" -cp "${JARS}" one.of.my.classes.Class1 "${ARGS}" > log.txt
```

as `./test1.sh` from command line, I get `Could not find or load main class`. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

1. Sorry for bad editing of the original question. Corrected.
2. `echo` produces `java -cp /my/dir/Dep1.jar:/my/dir/Dep2.jar:/my/dir/MainJar.jar one.of.my.classes.Class1 <args>`
3. I added building `CLASSPATH` trying to get the script to work. Removing it has no effect,i.e. I get the same exact error.
4. Is it possible that the JAR is build somehow incorrectly? I generate it by running an ant build from Eclipse.

Comment: Could you _echo_ the full generated command line ? And what is JARGS ? Oh....a typo for JARS ? ^^

Comment: JARGS typo -> missing jar -> missing Main class. Case closed.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Not so fast, Columbo.

Comment: use `${JEXE} ${JARS} one.of.my.classes.Class1 ${ARGS} > log.txt`

Comment: adding to the `CLASSPATH` and then using `-cp` with the same list is redundant just use `-cp` to limit side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script worked after I added

```
export PATH=$PATH:<path to java directory>
```